# Zeros over $F_4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the map $f(x, y) := x^3 + y^2 + y$.

What are the zeros $P_1, ..., P_n$ of $f$ over $F_4$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to solve the equation $y=\frac{1}{2} ( \sqrt{1-4x^3} -1)$...

Comment: @JohnD Yeah, that $\frac12$ is going to create problems over $\Bbb F_4$. On the other hand, there are only $4$ different values that $y$ can take. Why don't you try them all and see which ones have cube roots?

Comment: Yeah you're right @Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, take ${\Bbb F}_4= \{0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$, where $\alpha$ is root of $X^2+X+1\in{\Bbb Z}_2[X]$, i.e., $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$.

Write $f(X,Y)=Y^2+Y+X^3$.

Then $f(X,0) = X^3$, $f(X,1) = X^3$, $f(X,\alpha)=\alpha^2+\alpha+X^3 = X^3+1$, $f(X,\alpha^2) = (\alpha^2)^2+\alpha^2 + X^3 = X^3+1$.

But $X^3=0$ means $X=0$ and $X^3+1 = 0$ means $X=1,\alpha,\alpha^2$. Done.

Comment: Well this really makes sense! Thanks a lot! What if we consider the map $e: F_4 [x,y]_{<2} \to F_4^n , g(x, y) \to (g(P_1), ..., g(P_n))$ Why does Im(g) define a [8,3,5] code?

Comment: I mean $g(P_1)$ is $g(0)$, right? $g(P_2) = g(1)$ and so on. But why is this a [8,3,5] code?

Comment: I think its better to ask this as a separate question - section coding theory.